# преобразование словесного вида числа в число

Tags: python

Здравствуйте и снова я с тупым вопросом. У меня появилось необходимость перевести словесное представление числа (например: пять) в число (например: 5). В обратную сторону нашёл тучу решений, а вот так ни одного, поэтому и задал такой вот вопрос. Буду признателен за ответ и если можно пояснение, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите реализацию тут: https://github.com/SergeyShk/Word-to-Number-Russian

Comment: @floydya спасибо большое за помощь, всё отлично работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/SergeyShk/Word-to-Number-Russian - вот отличный пример. Вот так я его использую:

```py
from functions.timer_modules.extractor import NumberExtractor
print(NumberExtractor().replace_groups("сто минута"))
```

Дальше думаю сами разберётесь. В репозитории файл `extractor` и `number` это всё, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Эта задача решается не так тривиально, как формулируется. Мне приходилось заниматься подобной задачей и в нашей команде её решали с помощью парсеров (анализаторов).

Лексический и синтаксический анализатор широко используются при создании интерпретаторов и компиляторов. Сейчас популярны так называемые PEG-анализаторы.

Я писал парсеры для C#, и мы использовали библиотеку IronMeta. Вам для Python надо будет выбрать свою библиотеку. В частности, в Google я нашёл [Parsimonious](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious), но вы лучше повыбирайте сами.

Грамматика будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
zero = "ноль"
one = "один"
two = "два"
three = "три"
...
nine = "девять"
ones = one | two | three | ... | nine
eleven = "одинадцать"
twelve = "двенадцать"
...
nineteen = "девятнадцать"
teens = elevent | ... | twelve | ... | nineteen
ten = "десять"
twenty = "двадцать"
ninety = "девяности"
tens = ten | twenty | ... | ninety
number = zero | ones | teens | tens | tens ones
```

В визиторе, который описан в документации на Parsimonious, надо завести аккумулятор, в который надо прибавлять значения. `visit_twenty` добавит 20, `visit_nine` добавит 9, итого "двадцать девять" превратится в 29.

Comment: спасибо конечно, но мне уже скинули прелестный ответ, который отлично мне подходит. github.com/SergeyShk/Word-to-Number-Russian